# Simple Python sub

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import re  

Temp = "C4"
Num = 5
Temp = re.sub(r'(\w)\d',r'\1%s'%Num, Temp)
print Temp
```

I get the following error:

```
PS C:\...> .\try.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\try.py", line 10, in <module>
    Temp = re.sub(r'(\w)\d',r'\1%s'%Num, Temp)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 275, in filter
    return sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py", line 802, in expand_template
    raise error, "invalid group reference"
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r'\1%s'%Num` becomes the equivalent of `r'\15`, so this will actually be looking for group #15 which obviously doesn't exist.  To fix this, replace the `\1` in your replacement with `\g<1>`, that way it isn't affected by any digits that follow:

```
Temp = re.sub(r'(\w)\d',r'\g<1>%s'%Num, Temp)
```

Or alternatively, add the new digit after performing the replacement to remove the original digit:

```
Temp = '%s%s' % (re.sub(r'(\w)\d', r'\1', Temp), Num)
```

Comment: Thanks F.J! That solved the problem. I spent hours trying to figure it out.